# Trying to fill h:selectOneMenu when date is selected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

At this moment my code works but I have to select a date twice if I want to get properly information. I tried to change the ajax event to dateSelect, but it adds an hash in my URL and do nothing. I just want to keep its current behaviour, but selecting a date one single time.

Thanks in advance.

```
<h:form>
   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="medico" value="Médico:" />
        <h:inputText id="medico" value="#{pacienteControlador.pacienteActual.medico.nombre} #{pacienteControlador.pacienteActual.medico.apellidos}" disabled="true"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="fecha" value="Fecha:" />
        <p:calendar id="fecha" value="#{pacienteControlador.calendarManagedBean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
            <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{pacienteControlador.citasDisponibles()}" render="hora" />
        </p:calendar>
        <p:outputLabel for="hora" value="Hora:" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="hora" value="#{pacienteControlador.horaCita}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{pacienteControlador.listaHorasLibres}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Crear" action="#{pacienteControlador.crearCita()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Use p:ajax instead f:ajax

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="{pacienteControlador.citasDisponibles()}" update="hora" />
```